# How do I iterate through an ArrayList of custom objects from Intent and add them into LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList of custom FlightData objects within the intent. I load the intent and get the arraylist as null, and the foreach loop also forces me to use `Object` as type.

Saving arraylist into intent:

```java
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("FlightDataList", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) flightDataList);
```

Loading of intent:

```java
Intent intent = getIntent();
LinearLayout layout_datasheet =  findViewById(R.id.layout_datasheet);
List flightDataList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("FlightDataList");

if (flightDataList == null){
    Log.d("flightDataList_size", "FlightDataList is null"); // this fires
}

assert flightDataList != null;
for (Object data : flightDataList){
    data = (FlightData) data; // items in list are of type FlightData
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(data.toString());
    layout_datasheet.addView(tv);
}
```

My custom class' parcelable functions (x,y,time, has getters-setters):

```java
@Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeDouble(x);
        dest.writeDouble(y);
        dest.writeDouble(time);
    }

    public static final Creator<FlightData> CREATOR = new Creator<FlightData>() {
        @Override
        public FlightData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new FlightData(in);
        }

        @Override
        public FlightData[] newArray(int size) {
            return new FlightData[size];
        }
    };
```

Comment: what data is contained in your arraylist?  that is: only strings, strings and integers, strings integers adn other parcelables?  did you create a parcelable class for the flightDataList data structure?

Comment: 3 doubles, updated question with the implementation of parcelable. the IDEshows no error before runtime, i launch the app and after switching activities, the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

1.First Implement Parceable in your FlightData object model / pojo / class

2.`val flightDataList= ArrayList<FlightData>()`

3.`val args = Bundle()`

4.`args.putParcelableArrayList("FlightDataList", flightDataList)`

5.`intent.putExtra(args)`

Then to get list

`val flightDataList = context.getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("FlightDataList")`

Comment: i don't think you have to create a bundle... but i may be way off base on that

Comment: yeah its an alternative approch if direct `putParcelableArrayListExtra` didn't work

Comment: I did put the list into the bundle and the bundle into the intent. The bundle is not null finally, but the arraylist is still null. After putting it into the bundle I can get it with `getParcelableArrayList("FlightDataList")` in the same function (and activity) I put it in. But in the other activity it is null.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you have implemented Parcable in FlightData
https://medium.com/techmacademy/how-to-implement-and-use-a-parcelable-class-in-android-part-1-28cca73fc2d1

Answer (score 0):

did you try creating a datastructure that implements parcelable?

```
public class flightDataList implements Parcelable{
    String dataThingyString;
    int dataThingyInt;


    public flightDataList(String dataThingyString, int dataThingyInt){
        this.dataThingyString = dataThingyString;
        this.dataThingyInt = dataThingyInt;
    }

    public flightDataList(Parcle in){
        this.dataThingyString = in.readString();
        this.dataThingyInt = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags){
        dest.writeString(dataThingyString);
        dest.writeInt(dataThingyInt);
    }

    public static final Creator<flightDataList> CREATOR = new Creator<flightDataList>(){
        @Override
        public flightDataList createFromParcel(Parcel source){
            return new flightDataList(source);
        }

        @Override
        public flightDataList[] newArray(int size){
            return new flightDataList[size];
        }
    }

    public void setdataThingyString(String stringData){
        this.dataThingyString = stringData;
    }

    public void setdataThingyInt(int intData){
        this.dataThingyInt = intData;
    }

    public String getdataThingyString(){
        return dataThingyString;
    }

    public int getdataThingyInt(){
        return dataThingyInt;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents(){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: updated question. Could you tell me where did I mess it up? This was all auto-generated by the IDE. As you can see, it holds 3 doubles.

Comment: Burhan Khanzada below suggested using a bundle in the intent...  looking around a bit that seems to be a fairly standard method...  you might also want to check and see that your intent is actually being set before you begin the new activity and that the intent is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. The only thing that I am missing in your example is the constructor. It could explain the `null` your are getting.

Try adding this constructor for `FlightData`

```
  public FlightData(Parcel in) {
    x = in.readDouble();
    y = in.readDouble();
    time  = in.readDouble();
  }
```